# Quadratic equations ..

Tags: quadratics

The set of non-zero values of k such that the equation $|x^2-10x+9| =kx$ is satisfied by atleast one and atmost three values of x, lies in ___.

The answer is $(-\infty, -16] \cup [4 , \infty) $.

How do you get that ? 
 [image: OB and OA are slopes between which the value of 'k' is supposed to be.]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.StackExchange! Please follow $\LaTeX$ procedures and post your own attempt before asking questions.

Comment: The posted pic is so bad... that I will MSE can compile pstricks.

Comment: Congratulations on the picture. The scale is not quite right, but it tells the story very well.

Comment: I have posted some hints, not the full solution, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. Note that $|y|=kx$ iff $kx>0$ and $y=kx$ or $y=-kx$.
2. Using the previous hint, write down the two cases in consideration and isolate all the terms to one side so that the other side is $0$.
3. For each case, set the [discriminant](http://www.mathwords.com/d/discriminant_quadratic.htm) to be non-negative and solve.